# How to make a View of role?

Tags: 7, views, users

I need to make a page with the list of the roles (I have 10 roles in the site) and the possibilities of changing their name,I tried to use views but was not possible.
I want something like the drupal's role page, but just with the modify button.
Some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In views you cannot access to a list of roles, only to the user entity.

I suggest you to get this list of the roles by a drupal function

Try with [user_roles()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_roles/7)